# Send Email with image attachment using JBoss server from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, email, jboss

I am trying to send email with image attachment from my JBOSS server. I am using eclipse Ide. Where should I put my image resource that is to be sent at email attachment.

```
         BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
         String htmlText = "<H1>Hello</H1><img src=\"cid:image\">";
         messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlText, "text/html");
         // add it
         multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

         // second part (the image)
         messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
         DataSource fds = new FileDataSource("Logo.png");

         messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
         messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image>");

         // add image to the multipart
         multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

         // put everything together
         msg.setContent(multipart);
         // Send message
         Transport.send(msg);
```

In the above code I am providing Logo.png, where should I put that file in the folder hierarchy.

The folder structure is:

```
project-backend
-DeployedResources
-src
--main
---java
----com
-----abc
------utils
-------EmailUtil.java -> File with the email sending logic

---resources
----META-INF
-----persistence.xml

---webapp
----WEB_INF
-----beans.xml
-----web.xml
```

I tried placing that file at multiple locations by everytime I am get the error in line:
// Send message
Transport.send(msg);

The error is:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>   javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility.getEncoding(MimeUtility.java:226)
>   javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility.getEncoding(MimeUtility.java:299)
>   javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1375)
>   javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1021)
>   javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.updateHeaders(MimeMultipart.java:419)
>   javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1354)
>   javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateHeaders(MimeMessage.java:2107)
>   javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.saveChanges(MimeMessage.java:2075)
>   com.abc.utils.EmailUtil.sendEmail(EmailUtil.java:69)
>   javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:123)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by placing the resources in the bin folder of jboss server.